# BBcode regex for **bold text**

Tags: regex

I'm terrible with regex, but I've had a try and a Google (and even looked in reddit's source) and I'm still stuck so here goes:

My aim is to match the following 'codes' and replace them with the HTML tags. It's just the regex I'm stuck with.

```
**bold text**
_italic text_
~hyperlink~
```

Here's my attempts at the bold one:

```
^\*\*([.^\*]+)\*\*$
```

Why this isn't working? I'm using the preg syntax.

Comment: This is not a BBCode!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use:

```
\*\*(.[^*]*)\*\*
```

explanation:

```
\*\*      // match two *'s
(.        // match any character
[^*]      // that is not a *
*)        // continuation of any character
\*\*      // match two *'s
```

in a character class "[ ]" "^" is only significant if it's the first character. so `(.*)` matches anything, `(.[^*]*)` is match anything until literal *

**edit**: in response to comments to match asterisk within (ie `**bold *text**`), you'd have to use a non greedy match:

```
\*\*(.*?)\*\*
```

character classes are more efficient non greedy matches, but it's not possible to group within a character class ([see](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) "Parentheses and Backreferences...")

Comment: This does not match a string like this: 'What is **3 * 4**?' just because it has one asterisk in it.

Comment: I think you want to get rid of the period here. It will work for **, but _(.[^_]*)_ will turn __ _hi_ into <i></i>hi_, not <i></i> <i>hi</i>

Comment: Your first answer shouldn't have a dot, it will match on `***test**`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, get rid of the ^ and the $. Using those will only match a string that starts with ** and ends with **. Second, use the greedy quantifier to match as little text as possible, instead of making a character class for all characters other than asterisks.

Here's what I suggest:

```
\*\*(.+?)\*\*
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another regexp: `\*\*((?:[^*]|\*(?!\*))*)\*\*`

Example in Perl:

```
my %tag2re = (b => <<'RE_BOLD', i => '_([^_]*)_');
  \*\*(      # begin bold
    (?:[^*]  # non-star
    |        # or
    \*(?!\*) # single star
    )*       # zero or more times
  )\*\*      # end bold
RE_BOLD

my $text = <<BBCODE;
before  **bold and _italic_ *text
2nd line** after _just
           italic_ 
****
**tag _soup** as a result_
BBCODE

while (my ($tag, $re) = each %tag2re) {
    $text =~ s~$re~<$tag>$1</$tag>~gsx;
}
print $text;
```

It prints:

```
before  <b>bold and <i>italic</i> *text
2nd line</b> after <i>just
           italic</i> 
<b></b>
<b>tag <i>soup</b> as a result</i>
```

Or as html:

```
before  bold and italic *text
2nd line after just
           italic 

tag soup as a result
```

Stackoverflow's interpretation is:

before  **bold and *italic* *text
2nd line** after *just
           italic*

---

**tag *soup*** as a result

Answer (score 1):

```
\*\*(.*?)\*\*
```

that will work for the **bold text**.

just replace the ** with _ or ~ for the others